# Remove dupllicates from Multi-dimensional object array fetched via wordpress query

Tags: php, object, multidimensional-array, duplicates

I am trying to get `POST` data based on a query, but I get duplicate results. I tried sort regular but still it shows many duplicates. What should I do?

My code (as shown below) prints repeated object IDs in the `foreach` loop. Here, `object_id = 2423` repeats. I want to keep one and delete the other other.

```
$vbn = $wpdb->get_results($query_cat_filter);
$bbc = array_unique($vbn, SORT_REGULAR);

foreach( $bbc as $cOM){
    print_r($bbc);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [object_id] => 2415
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 242
            [term_order] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [object_id] => 2423
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 242
            [term_order] => 0
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [object_id] => 2423
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 312
            [term_order] => 0
        )
)
```

**How can I remove these duplicate values?**

Comment: How do you know which one to keep since the `term_taxonomy_id` values are different, or is that unimportant?

Comment: this duplicate values appear due to merge array of two queries so here in my case 242 is parent category id and 312 is its sub category so its shows duplicate as its assigned at both places.Is there any we to remove any of them? taxonomy id is not important here for me

Answer (score 0):

There maybe be a native function to do that, however, when I want to organize by key, I use a function like so. *Note: I haven't tried it on an object, so you may have to first convert your objects to array by using `(array)`*:

```
<?php
    function organize($array = array(), $assockey = false,$forcerows = false)
        {
            if(!empty($array)) {
                    $i = 0;
                    foreach($array as $rows) {
                            if(is_array($rows)) {
                                    foreach($rows as $key => $value) {
                                            if(!empty($rows[$assockey])) {
                                                $_key   =   $rows[$assockey];
                                                $new[$_key][$i][$key]   =   $value;
                                            }
                                        }
                                }
                            $i++;
                        }
                }
            if(isset($new)) {
                    foreach($new as $key => $value) {
                            if(count($value) == 1) {
                                    $keyName    =   array_keys($value);
                                    $new[$key]  =   ($forcerows == true)? array_values($value):$value[$keyName[0]];
                                }
                            else {
                                    $new[$key]  =   array_values($value);
                                }
                        }
                }

            return (isset($new))? $new : $array;
        }

 // Starting input      
 $vals  =   array(
            '0' => array(
                    'object_id' => 2415,
                    'term_taxonomy_id' => 242,
                    'term_order' => 0,),
            '1' => array(
                    'object_id' => 2423,
                    'term_taxonomy_id' => 242,
                    'term_order' => 0,
                ),
            '2' => array(
                    'object_id' => 2423,
                    'term_taxonomy_id' => 312,
                    'term_order' => 0
                )
            );

    // Organize by key          
    $arr    =   organize($vals,'object_id',true);
    print_r($arr);
?>
```

Gives you an array like so:

```
Array
(
    [2415] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [object_id] => 2415
                    [term_taxonomy_id] => 242
                    [term_order] => 0
                )

        )

    [2423] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [object_id] => 2423
                    [term_taxonomy_id] => 242
                    [term_order] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [object_id] => 2423
                    [term_taxonomy_id] => 312
                    [term_order] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

From here, you can just use key `[0]` of each array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$vbn = array(
    (object)array(
        'object_id' => 2135,
        'term_taxonomy' => 242,
        'term_order' => 0,
    ),
    (object)array(
        'object_id' => 3245,
        'term_taxonomy' => 312,
        'term_order' => 0,
    ),
    (object)array(
        'object_id' => 3245,
        'term_taxonomy' => 242,
        'term_order' => 0,
    ),
    (object)array(
        'object_id' => 5623,
        'term_taxonomy' => 714,
        'term_order' => 0,
    )
);
```

The new arrays could be made associative, for simplicity I went with numeric.

### DEDUP CODE

```
foreach($vbn as $key => $obj){
 $value = get_object_vars($obj);
 $vbn2[$value['object_id']] = array($value['term_taxonomy'],$value['term_order']);
}
```

OR

```
foreach($vbn as $obj) {
    $result[$obj->object_id] = array($obj->term_taxonomy,$obj->term_order);
}
```

### NEW FOREACH

```
foreach($vbn2 as $key => $value){
  echo "$key => $value[0], $value[1]\n";
}
```

### RESULT

```
2135 => 242, 0
3245 => 242, 0
5623 => 714, 0

var_export($vbn2);

array (
  2135 => 
  array (
    'term_taxonomy' => 242,
    'term_order' => 0,
  ),
  3245 => 
  array (
    'term_taxonomy' => 242,
    'term_order' => 0,
  ),
  5623 => 
  array (
    'term_taxonomy' => 714,
    'term_order' => 0,
  ),
```

### ASSOCIATIVE

Results are same as above.

```
 var_export($vbn2);

foreach($vbn as $key => $obj){
 $value = get_object_vars($obj);
 $vbn2[$value['object_id']] = array('term_taxonomy'=>$value['term_taxonomy'],'term_order'=>$value['term_order']);
}
foreach($vbn2 as $key => $value){
  echo "$key => " . $value['term_taxonomy'] . ', ' . $value['term_order'] . "\n";
}

array (
  2135 => 
  array (
    'term_taxonomy' => 242,
    'term_order' => 0,
  ),
  3245 => 
  array (
    'term_taxonomy' => 242,
    'term_order' => 0,
  ),
  5623 => 
  array (
    'term_taxonomy' => 714,
    'term_order' => 0,
  ),
)
```

### If You Don't Mind an Ugly Mess

It dedups just the same but the result is ugly.

```
foreach($vbn as $obj) {
    $vbn2[$obj->object_id] = (object) array($obj->term_taxonomy,$obj->term_order);
 }  
 var_export($vbn2);
```

Output:

```
array (
  2135 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'term_taxonomy' => 242,
     'term_order' => 0,
  )),
  3245 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'term_taxonomy' => 242,
     'term_order' => 0,
  )),
  5623 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'term_taxonomy' => 714,
     'term_order' => 0,
  )),
)
```

OR
if you don't mind wasting memory

```
foreach($vbn as $object) {
    $vbn2[$object->object_id] = $object;
}
var_export($vbn2);
```

output:

```
array (
  2135 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'object_id' => 2135,
     'term_taxonomy' => 242,
     'term_order' => 0,
  )),
  3245 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'object_id' => 3245,
     'term_taxonomy' => 242,
     'term_order' => 0,
  )),
  5623 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'object_id' => 5623,
     'term_taxonomy' => 714,
     'term_order' => 0,
  )),
)
```

Comment: No need for `get_object_vars`.  Why not just `$vbn2[$obj->object_id] = $obj`?

Comment: @AbraCadaver #1. The output is a mess and ugly, see end of my post. #2. wastes space by duplicating `object_id`,. And #3. Arrays are easier and cleaner to work with than objects

Answer (score 0):

Simple enough:

```
foreach($vbn as $object) {
    $result[$object->object_id] = $object;
}
```

And if you want to reorder the keys afterward:

```
$result = array_values($result);
```

Alternately, if you don't mind getting arrays instead of objects, use `ARRAY_A` in `get_results` (PHP >= 5.5.0 needed for `array_column`):

```
$vbn = $wpdb->get_results($query_cat_filter, ARRAY_A);
$vbn = array_column($vbn, null, 'object_id');

//or for only `object_id`
$vbn = array_column($vbn, 'object_id');
```

Comment: concept looks familiar.

Comment: Yep, considering there's about only one concept to choose from.